# convert time span duration to decimal

Tags: c#, decimal

I have subtracted one date from another and got back the difference in HH:MM. I need to change this to the number of hours with a decimal point in c#.

For Example:

```
3:30 becomes 3.5
3:15 becomes 3.25
3:45 becomes 3.75
```

Comment: You're posting to ask how to divide a number by 60?

Comment: @devnull: That wouldn't actually be the cleanest solution in this case. There's no need to deal with individual components.

Answer (score 3):

If you subtract one `DateTime` from another, you get a `TimeSpan` - not a "difference in HH:mm". That may be how it's displayed, but it's not the underlying data.

If you take the [`TotalHours`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalhours.aspx) property, that will give you a `double` value which would be what you want (3.5 for 3 hours and 30 minutes, for example).